# spark - java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/user/.sparkStaging/

Tags: apache-spark

Problem

Submit the spark job but got the error. How to fix?

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2
export SPARK_MASTER=yarn
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/spark-3.1.2
export SPARK_DEPLOY_MODE=cluster
export SPARK_EXAMPLE_JAR="spark-examples_2.12-3.1.2.jar"
    
    
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  $SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/$SPARK_EXAMPLE_JAR 10 \
  --master $SPARK_MASTER \
  --deploy-mode $SPARK_DEPLOY_MODE
```

```
22/02/18 22:27:36 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1645180452555_0008 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1645180452555_0008_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-02-18 22:27:36.433]File file:/home/user/.sparkStaging/application_1645180452555_0008/__spark_libs__7275973196548620925.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/user/.sparkStaging/application_1645180452555_0008/__spark_libs__7275973196548620925.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.verifyAndCopy(FSDownload.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:415)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

```
$ ls $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
ls: cannot access '/opt/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/etc/hadoop': Permission denied
```

### Clue

The files should be `hdfs://.../.sparkStaging/`, not `file://...`.

```
File file:/home/user/.sparkStaging/...
```

Comment: Getting the same error: In logs it is like : Uploading resource hdfs://193.88.56.7/user/sm/spark-libs.jar -> file:/home/spend/.sparkStaging/application_1653488732788_0019/spark-libs.jar but in the cluster logs it is like : Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-06-13 09:39:35.396]File file:/home/spend/.sparkStaging/application_1653488732788_0018/spark-libs.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spend/.sparkStaging/application_1653488732788_0018/spark-libs.jar does not exist